# Do Time Stories combats during travel between Locations use up Time Units?

Tags: time-stories

In *Time Stories*, do battles, contests and challenges that take place as encounters during travel between locations use up Time Units?

I don't think it's really covered in the base rules, but some of the expansion adventures add encounters when moving between locations, and I'm wondering if those use up time units the same way they do at locations?

And (in the absence of specific instructions, of course), if a scenario gives you the ability to retreat from Locked combat, can you retreat from an encounter combat, and if so, would that get the party to avoid that combat if every party member got away, and would it take a Time Unit to retreat, or not. (It takes one character Time Unit to retreat to another Space at a Location, but when traveling it might be thought not to add to the rolled travel time for moving between locations?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said the rules don't seem to cover these exact scenarios, but the way I interpreted the rules I assume that any test or action that causes me to roll the dice costs a TU unless the text specifically says it doesn't cost any TU.  My main reason for thinking this is that the base rules do specify that all tests cost a TU, and some expansions *do* have cards with text specifying that a test can be performed without spending TU.

Comment: We're now playing "The Marcy Case" scenario, and it has a similar encounter mechanic, which explicitly says that each combat round in an encounter does use a time unit.